# Como estilizar um elemento que não é filho do elemento usado no seletor

Tags: css3, operadores

Tenho o código abaixo, onde quero que, ao clicar no toogle (que é um `input[type=checkbox]`), um outro elemento, que é uma classe de outra div, abaixo, seja estilizada. No código que segue, eu faço uma tentativa usando o operador irmão geral `~` que não está funcionando, penso que é porque a classe `.ringDireita` não é filha da div botões, embora esteja "declarada" abaixo dela.

O que há de errado no uso de seletores ou o que mais pode ser feito?

```css
body {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #262626;
}

#botoes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
}

#botoes input[type=checkbox]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  transition: .1s;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 15px #ffffff;
}

#botoes input[type=checkbox] {
  position: relative;
  background: #b9b9c8;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  outline: none;
}

#botoes input:checked[type=checkbox]::before {
  left: 40px;
}

#botoes input:checked[type=checkbox] {
  background: dodgerBlue;
}

.ringDireita {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.ringDireita::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff000;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animateCircleDireita 2s linear infinite;
}

.ringEsquerda {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.ringEsquerda::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animateCircleEsquerda 2s linear infinite;
}

.ringCentro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.ringCentro::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4000ff;
  border-right: 3px solid #4000ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animateCircleCentro 2s linear infinite;
}

span.direita {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: animateDireita 2s linear infinite;
}

span.direita::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff000;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff000, 0 0 40px #fff000, 0 0 60px #fff000, 0 0 80px #fff000, 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .3), 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 0, .1);
}

span.esquerda {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: animateEsquerda 2s linear infinite;
}

span.esquerda::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 40px #fff, 0 0 60px #fff, 0 0 80px #fff, 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

span.centro {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: animateCentro 2s linear infinite;
}

span.centro::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4000ff;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #4000ff, 0 0 40px #4000ff, 0 0 60px #4000ff, 0 0 80px #4000ff, 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 255, .3), 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
}

@keyframes animateCircleDireita {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateCircleEsquerda {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateCircleCentro {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateDireita {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateEsquerda {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateCentro {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(495deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Teste de pontos circulantes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="botoes">
    Hidden Rings
    <input type="checkbox"> Collision Rings
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="ringDireita">
    <span class="direita"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="ringEsquerda">
    <span class="esquerda"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="ringCentro">
    <span class="centro"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu pensamento está correto! Quando vc coloca o seletor `~` em um `input:checkbox` que está dentro do um *container*, independente do estado desse `checkbox` (checked ou não) vc não consegue atingir um elemento que está fora desse *container*, ou um elemento que não seja filho ou irmão desse `inpud:chekbox`

Para resolver essa questão vc pode usar uma `label` com o atributo `for="meuid"` para atingir um `input:chekbox:id="meuid"` que está escondido fora desse *container*. No caso eu usei dois IDs `#hide` e `#coli` em dois `inputs` com `display:none` que ficam antes de todos os elementos, assim eu posso usa o seletor `~` para atingir qualquer elemento que venha depois desses `inputs`. E ao clicar na `label` eu consigo atingir os `inputs` e muda-los para `checked` ou não.

Nesse exemplo eu fiz um Btn para esconder os Anéis e outro Btn para esconder as Bolinhas.  Deixei uns comentário no código para vc entender melhor.

```css
body
{
 margin:5px; padding:0; background:#262626;
}
#botoes
{
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 color:#fff;
 margin:5px; 
}
#botoes label::before
{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#000;
 transition:.1s;
 transform:scale(1.1);
 box-shadow: 0 0px 15px #ffffff;
 
}
/* esconde os inputs com display:none */
#hide,
#coli 
{
    display: none;
}

/* aqui vc usa na verdade o label, e não o input */
#botoes label 
{ 
position:relative;
background:#b9b9c8;
width:80px; 
height:40px;
border:none;
float:right;
border-radius:20px;
-webkit-appearance:none;
margin-bottom:15%;
outline:none; 
cursor: pointer;
}

/* seleciona apenas a labrl com o atributo for correpondente */
#hide:checked ~ #botoes [for="hide"]::before,
#coli:checked ~ #botoes [for="coli"]::before
{
 left:40px;
}

#hide:checked ~ #botoes [for="hide"],
#coli:checked ~ #botoes [for="coli"]
{
 background:dodgerBlue;
}


#hide:checked ~ .ringDireita::before,
#hide:checked ~ .ringEsquerda::before,
#hide:checked ~ .ringCentro::before
{
 border:3px solid transparent;
}
#coli:checked ~ .ringDireita > span,
#coli:checked ~ .ringEsquerda > span,
#coli:checked ~ .ringCentro > span
{
 opacity: 0;
}


.ringDireita
{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 background:transparent;
 border:3px solid #3c3c3c;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.ringDireita::before
{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 top:-3px; 
 left:-3px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 border:3px solid transparent;
 border-top:3px solid #fff000;
 border-right:3px solid #fff000;
 border-radius:50%;
 animation:animateCircleDireita 2s linear infinite;
}
.ringEsquerda
{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 width:120px;
 height:120px;
 background:transparent;
 border:3px solid #3c3c3c;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.ringEsquerda::before
{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 top:-3px; 
 left:-3px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 border:3px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:3px solid #fff;
 border-right:3px solid #fff;
 border-radius:50%;
 animation:animateCircleEsquerda 2s linear infinite;
}
.ringCentro
{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 background:transparent;
 border:3px solid #3c3c3c;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.ringCentro::before
{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 top:-3px; 
 left:-3px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 border:3px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:3px solid #4000ff;
 border-right:3px solid #4000ff;
 border-radius:50%;
 animation:animateCircleCentro 2s linear infinite;
}
span.direita
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:calc(50% - 2px);
 left:50%;
 width:50%;
 height:4px;
 background:transparent;
 transform-origin:left;
 animation: animateDireita 2s linear infinite;
}
span.direita::before
{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#fff000;
 top:-8px;
 right:-8px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff000,
 0 0 40px #fff000,
 0 0 60px #fff000,
 0 0 80px #fff000,
 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.3),
 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,0,.1);
}
span.esquerda
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:calc(50% - 2px);
 left:50%;
 width:50%;
 height:4px;
 background:transparent;
 transform-origin:left;
 animation: animateEsquerda 2s linear infinite; 
 
}

span.esquerda::before
{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#fff;
 top:-8px;
 right:-8px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff,
 0 0 40px #fff,
 0 0 60px #fff,
 0 0 80px #fff,
 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,255,.3),
 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
span.centro
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:calc(50% - 2px);
 left:50%;
 width:50%;
 height:4px;
 background:transparent;
 transform-origin:left;
 animation: animateCentro 2s linear infinite; 
 
}

span.centro::before
{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#4000ff;
 top:-8px;
 right:-8px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px #4000ff,
 0 0 40px #4000ff,
 0 0 60px #4000ff,
 0 0 80px #4000ff,
 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,255,.3),
 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,255,.1);
}


@keyframes animateCircleDireita
{
 0%
 {
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
 100%
 {
  transform:rotate(360deg);
 }
} 
@keyframes animateCircleEsquerda
{
 0%
 {
  transform:rotate(360deg);
 }
 100%
 {
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
} 
@keyframes animateCircleCentro
{
 0%
 {
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
 100%
 {
  transform:rotate(360deg);
 }
} 

@keyframes animateDireita
{
 0%
 {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
 }
 100%
 {
  transform:rotate(405deg);
 }
} 
@keyframes animateEsquerda
{
 0%
 {
  transform:rotate(315deg);
 }
 100%
 {
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
 }
} 
@keyframes animateCentro
{
 0%
 {
  transform:rotate(135deg);
 }
 100%
 {
  transform:rotate(495deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- os inputs devem vir antes dos elementos que vc quer atingir com ~ -->
<input hidden id="hide" type="checkbox">
<input hidden id="coli" type="checkbox">

<div id="botoes">
    Hidden Rings
    <!-- agora é uma label e não o input -->
    <label for="hide"></label>
    Collision Rings
    <label for="coli"></label>
</div>

<div class="ringDireita">
    <span class="direita"></span>
</div>
<div class="ringEsquerda">
    <span class="esquerda"></span>
</div>
<div class="ringCentro">
    <span class="centro"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: hugocsl. Boa solução. Até pensei no label de alguma forma (pq podemos fazer referência  externa com ele pelo for) só não sabia como. Se entendi bem, posso usar seletor ~  com elemento de um container qualquer desde que o elemento de referência, no caso o input, não esteja "trancado" em outro container, mesmo se esse outro container está acima, é isso?  No seu caso, deu certo pq o input estava no container <body>, digamos “destrancado”, podendo ser usado em refer. por qualquer elemento abaixo, ok? Se eu colocasse o seu input dentro de uma div qualquer, voltaria a não funcionar a referência, ok?

Comment: @Fernandes perfeito, vc entendeu direitinho. Se vc trancar o input dentro de um container ele não consegue atingir mais ninguém, só o que estiver abaixo dele e dentro do mesmo container . Eh isso ai, por isso diz a malandragem de jogar o input pra fora do container e checar ele com a label usando o id do for :)